# CONF file in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 12.04, 18.04

i have /etc/init/myserver.conf file is ubuntu 12.04 worked.

in ubuntu 18.04 not worked.

```
# masterserver - start master server service 

description "Service that starts master.sh"
author "<hadjieff>"

# When to start the service
start on runlevel [2345]

# When to stop the service
stop on runlevel [016]

# Automatically restart process if crashed
respawn

# Essentially lets upstart know the process will detach itself to the background
expect fork

# Run before process
pre-start script
    # Put bash code here if necessary
end script

# Start the process
script
    cd /home/hadjieff/hadjieff/server
    sudo java -Djava.security.policy=security.policy -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.1.91  -cp . -jar Registar.jar --xbee=true --test=false
end script
```

Comment: I doubt it's because of Ubuntu 18.04, rather due to a newer mysql version. Thus, not sure, if this is the right place to ask. Maybe better ask on serverfault ?